# Upload more than one image with .csv for thumbnail galley

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been looking for way to do this and i can't seem to work it out?

Basically i want to be able to add the images into the spreadsheet that will display in the thumbnail section of the product under the base image.

One post mentioned "_media_gallery" along with other attributes to set the position of them etc and i tried this but nothing happened?

Anyone have any info on this?

Might i add i am talking about multiple images to be added to one single line?
Like "/image1.jpg|/image2.jpg" and so on.